# w3wp.exe memory usage remains high after making web service calls

Tags: php, web-services, w3wp

I have set up one server with a PHP application and an .asmx web service application.

My PHP application makes frequent calls to web service functions inside this .asmx file. They in turn retrieve data from a database to be used in the PHP application. Here is my PHP code:

```
public function callService($file, $web_service, $parameters){
    if(defined("WEB_SERVICES_PATH")){
        try{
            $wsdl = WEB_SERVICES_PATH.$file."?wsdl";
            $client = new SoapClient ($wsdl, array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE) );                
            $result = $client->{$web_service}($parameters)->{$web_service."Result"};
            return $result;
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
          //handle error
        }
    }
}
```

I noticed in some instances that some web service calls cause the w3wp process to chew up a lot of memory. In some instances, the process will start of at around 80,000KB but then grow to around 800,000KB

Furthermore, the process seems to linger at around 800,000kb unless i kill it or restart IIS.

I have effectively two questions about this. Firstly, why would the memory not be released after the web service calls? and secondly, what factors would cause the w3wp process from chewing up so much memory?

Comment: PHP knows to free the memory it has used, but the container it lives inside [w3wp.exe] does not not. You can set the 'max requests' in your worker pool settings to recycle the workers more frequently, but that's a bandaid. A better solution is to set up PHP as FastCGI so that PHP doesn't have to run inside a container and can manage its memory directly with the OS. That said, a php process using 80MB of memory is bloated enough, but 800MB probably means there's something wrong. Optimize your code.

Comment: Cool. The only problem is i dont know how to find out what exactly is wrong with the code. The data sent and returned from the web services rarely exceeds 1kb